# How do I declare "Member Fields" in Java?

Tags: java, android

This question probably reveals my total lack of knowledge in Java. But let me first show you what I thought was the correct way to declare a "member field":

```
public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

private Object mTitleText;
private Object mBodyText;
```

I'm following a google's notepad tutorial for android ([here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html)) and they simply said: "Note that mTitleText and mBodyText are member fields (you need to declare them at the top of the class definition)." I thought I got it and then realized that this little snippet of code wasn't working.

```
if (title != null) {
            mTitleText.setText(title);
        }
        if (body != null) {
            mBodyText.setText(body);
        }
```

So either I didn't set the "member fields" correctly which I thought all that was needed was to declare them private Objects at the top of the NoteEdit class or I'm missing something else. Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

I was asked to show where these fields were being intialized here is another code snippet hope that it's helpful...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
    Long mRowId;
    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
```

So basically the error that is showing up is coming from eclipse:
"The method setText(String) is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: Need more code to help you. Where are mTitleText initialized for instance? You must have `mTitleText = something` somewhere

Comment: Look three lines above the "Note that mTitleText and mBodyText are member fields" bit. That's where they get assigned, which is the part you're missing.

Comment: "this little snippet of code wasn't working" - Compile error? Runtime error? Details? The code certainly looks fine (without context).

Comment: Thanks for helping me express my question better. I think it's helping me get the answer I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare fields and variables, it's usually helpful to give them a more specific `static type` than Object.  Because you have declared `mTitleText` as an `Object`, the compiler only knows how to invoke methods on the general [Object class definition](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).  `setText` is not such a method, so it's not legal to call it without a cast or other trickery.

What you should do is figure out the type that your field should be.  I don't know Android, but I presume that there is a text label class which defines your `setText` method.  If you change your fields to be defined as that,

```
private EditText mTitleText;
```

you will find that things should work much better :-)

Comment: In fact, one of the primary design goals of java was to provide a robust, strongly typed language.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Schlansker for your fast response.

Comment: You should not propage Hungarian notation in your example code.

Comment: @Steve Kuo:  it's part of the Android style guidelines.

Comment: My intent was to show the minimal change that solved the problem.  I don't personally use notations like this, but I'm not here to preach :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set those two fields somewhere else, they are not being initialized. So when you use them later, they are `null` and are causing exceptions. Java reference types initialize to `null`. Basic data types, which are not `null`able, initialize to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your mBodyText field needs to be typed to allow access to the setText method.

e.g:

```
private BodyText mBodyText;
```

Answer (score 0):

its not working because your objects not initialized.
mTitleText text should be a TextView 
then you need to initialize it

```
mTitleText = findViewById( R.id.yourviewid );
```

and then do

```
mTitleText.setText(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are marked as private so you can't the them outside of your class. If you want to get access outside of your class you have to use the keyword public in front of your field. BUT this is not recommended use properties instead

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to assign values to the two member variables. I believe the NoteEdit class has a layout xml file associated with it. You need to assign the text field objects from that layout to the objects before you try to reference their properties.

```
mTitleText = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.name_of_the_field_in_the_layout_file )
```

The answer above is also correct. You should assign types to those variables at the top of your class, not just make them `Objects`

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the name and type of a reference is one thing; initializing it to point to a valid memory location on the heap is another.  You need to initialize data members in a constructor for your class.

The default constructor initializes references to null by default.  If you haven't written a constructor to initialize your data member references, that could be an explanation why you're having trouble.